# filter reactions from specific discord.js

Tags: discord.js

Hello I'm making a Discord music bot which will have reaction roles so users can control the bot without typing a command. I'm currently stuck at the filtration as I want to have it so the person who had started the music can only control the bot can anybody help me?

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => user.id !== message.client.user.id;
var collector = playingMessage.createReactionCollector(filter, {
    time: song.duration > 0 ? song.duration * 1000 : 600000
});

collector.on("collect", (reaction, user) => {
    if (!queue) return;
    const member = message.guild.member(user);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the user id being the client user id change it to whatever user id you want to be able to react. Assuming that the `<Message>` variable is stored as `message` you could do:

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => user.id === message.author.id;
```